# Prove that $\left(A+B\right)^{2}\nmid A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}$

Tags: induction, divisibility, solution-verification, coprime

Let it be A and B two coprime positive integers. I know how to prove by induction that $A+B\mid A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}$, but I am having a bit trouble proving that $\left(A+B\right)^{2}\nmid A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}$.

For the case $n=1$ I have managed to prove it in the following way:

$$A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}=A^{3}+B^{3}$$

$$A^{3}+B^{3}=A^{2}(A+B)+B\left(B^{2}-A^{2}\right)$$

$$A^{3}+B^{3}=A^{2}(A+B)+B\left(A+B\right)\left(B-A\right)$$

$$A^{3}+B^{3}=\left(A+B\right)\left(A^{2}+B^{2}-AB\right)$$

As $\left(A+B\right)^{2}=A^{2}+B^{2}+2AB$, then we have that $A^{2}+B^{2}-AB=\left(A+B\right)^{2}-3AB$.

Thus, substituting, we get that

$$A^{3}+B^{3}=\left(A+B\right)\left(\left(A+B\right)^{2}-3AB\right)$$

$\left(A+B\right)^{2}\mid A^{3}+B^{3}$ only if $\left(A+B\right)\mid\left(A+B\right)^{2}-3AB$. As $\left(A+B\right)\mid\left(A+B\right)^{2}$, then it follows that $\left(A+B\right)\mid\left(A+B\right)^{2}-3AB$ only if $\left(A+B\right)\mid3AB$.

As A and B are coprime, it follows that $A+B\nmid3AB$. Therefore,

$$\left(A+B\right)^{2}\nmid A^{3}+B^{3}$$

The problem is that it seems not easy (or maybe possible) to apply induction on this method.

My questions are:

- Is the above proof correct?
- How could it be proved (if possible) that $\left(A+B\right)^{2}\nmid A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not hold even for $n=1$, consider $A=1,B=2$, then $(A+B)^2=9$ and $A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}=1+2^{3}=9$.

Comment: In particular, your argument for $n=1$ is correct up until:
$$\text{"As $A$ and $B$ are coprime, it follows that $A+B\nmid3AB$.}"$$

Comment: Thanks for the review, you are correct! So the proof is correct for $A,B>1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is false. We show how to find counterexamples.

Since we know that $$A^{2n+1}+B^{2n+1}=(A+B)(A^{2n}-A^{2n-1}B+\dots-AB^{2n-1}+B^{2n}),$$ it is equivalent to finding $A,B$ such that $$A+B\mid A^{2n}-A^{2n-1}B+\dots-AB^{2n-1}+B^{2n},$$ which is the same as $$A^{2n}-A^{2n-1}B+\dots-AB^{2n-1}+B^{2n}\equiv 0\pmod{A+B}.$$

However, we have from $A\equiv -B\pmod{A+B}$ that
\begin{align*}
A^{2n}-A^{2n-1}B+\dots-AB^{2n-1}+B^{2n}&\equiv (-B)^{2n}-(-B)^{2n-1}B+\dots-(-B)B^{2n-1}+B^{2n}\pmod{A+B}\\
&\equiv (2n+1)\cdot B^{2n}\pmod{A+B}.
\end{align*}

As such, we see that counterexamples can be constructed by selecting the value of $n$ such that $A+B\mid 2n+1$. For example, $(A,B,n)=(3,4,3)$ is a counterexample because $$(3+4)^2=49\mid 18571=3^7+4^7.$$

Comment: Very good start.

Comment: Brilliant @nukelauncher! Thanks a lot